# Where does Greasemonkey cache scripts that are added with the "@require" keyword?

Tags: cache, greasemonkey

Where does it cache the scripts that are added with the "@require" keyword? I'd like to know where it is on Mac OS X, preferably, but if you know where it is on another system then it shouldn't be hard to find on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GM stores all of a scripts data within it's own folder within the `gm_scripts` folder residing in your Firefox profile folder. [To find your profile folder please read this page](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles).

So to find the `@require`'d files for script `xyz` look in: `%Firefox Profile%/gm_scripts/xyz/`

Answer (score 3):

That's no longer true with recent Firefox - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851793) which tells that they are hidden away in a sqlite database.